# How to compute $\bar z^2+z-1/4 = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute  the solution of $\bar z^2+z-1/4 = 0$ without passing by putting $z =a+ib$ ,I need the exponentiel solution

Answer (score 10):

If $z$ is a solution, the conjugating gives $z^2+\bar{z}-1/4=0$. Subtract from this the original identity, getting
$$
z^2-\bar{z}^2-(z-\bar{z})=0
$$
so either $z=\bar{z}$ or $z+\bar{z}=1$.

In the first case the equation becomes
$$
z^2+z-\frac{1}{4}=0
$$
and in the second case
$$
(1-z)^2+z-\frac{1}{4}=0
$$

Answer (score 5):

Since the OP requested specifically a solution that used polar coordinates, we proceed, "brute force."

First, we write $z=\rho e^{i\phi}$ and $\bar z=\rho e^{-i\phi}$.

Then, we have

$$\bar z^2+z-\frac14=0\implies \rho^2 e^{-i2\phi}+\rho e^{i\phi}-\frac14=0$$

Equating real and imaginary parts yields

$$\rho^2 \cos (2\phi)+\rho \cos(\phi)-\frac14=0 \tag 1$$

and

$$-\rho^2 \sin (2\phi)+\rho \sin(\phi)=0 \tag 2$$

Equation $(2)$ has three solutions; (i) $\rho =0$, (ii) $\phi=n\pi$, and (iii) $\rho \cos \phi =\frac12$.

**CASE (i):** Obviously, $\rho =0$ does not satisfy $(1)$ and is not a solution to the problem of interest.

**CASE (ii):**  If $\phi =n\pi$, then $(1)$ reduces to

$$\rho^2+(-1)^n\rho-\frac14=0\implies \rho = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}+ \sqrt{2}}{2}$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{z=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{2}}{2}}$$

**CASE (iii):**  If $\rho \cos \phi =\frac12$, then $(1)$ reduces to

$$\rho^2 (2\cos (2\phi) -1)+\rho \cos \phi -\frac14=0 \implies \rho = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \,\,\text{and}\,\,\phi= \pm\arccos(\sqrt{3}/3)$$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{z=\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{2}}{2}}$$